# How to fix BasicAuth for Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing an SpringBoot app. When I do requests with Postman - I get this error VERY OFTEN:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticationIsRequired(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/restaurants").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

        //Set enable when frontend added
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

How to fix it? I need to do request from Postman, so I can't change the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Authorization` tab in your Postman window ( it's under the request type ) and select 'Basic Auth' and fill in your credentials if you're doing any request other than "/", "/registration", "/restaurants".

Comment: Postman gives me that error in 50% of requests after I add that parameters of Authorization

Comment: Make sure that you set the `Authorization` settings from above in each request.

Comment: I'm sure. My colleagues have the same problem